# Comparting two ArrayList<String> lists in Java

Tags: java, string, list, dictionary, compare

Okay... So what I've been trying to do is compare two lists: words and d. The words they have in common need to be added to a third list: realWords.

Dictionary is just a list in a different class that has a bunch of words in it.

```
List<String> realWords = new ArrayList<String>();
Dictionary d = new Dictionary();
```

These are the things I've tried and haven't worked (and by "worked" I mean the output is nothing, no errors):

Attempt 1

```
List<String> realWords = new ArrayList<String>(words);
    realWords.retainAll(d);
```

Attempt 2

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        if (d.contains(words.get(i))){      
            realWords.add(words.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Attempt 3

```
for(String word : words) {
        if (d.contains(word)) {
            realWords.add(word);
        }
    }
```

Attempt 4

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < d.size(); i++) {
            if(words.get(i) == d.get(j)) {
                realWords.add(words.get(i));
            }       
        }
    }
```

And then after that portion of code I'm missing:

```
return realWords;
```

Thanks in advance!

*Edit1: The code for Dictionary.java is:*

```
package a1;

import java.util.*;

public class Dictionary extends ArrayList<String> {

    public Dictionary() {

        this.add("abalone");
        this.add("abandon");
        this.add("abashed");
        this.add("abashes");
        this.add("abasing");
        this.add("abating");
        this.add("abdomen");
        this.add("abducts");
        this.add("abetted");
        this.add("abetter");
        this.add("abettor");
        this.add("abiding");
        this.add("ability");
        this.add("abjured");
        this.add("abjures");
        this.add("abolish");
        this.add("aborted");
        this.add("abounds");
        this.add("abraded");
        // and then more words

        }
    }
```

NOTE: This code was provided to us and cannot be changed.

Comment: `Dictionary` doesn't appear to be a `List`. Can you post the code for it?

Comment: You would need to show the code for a Dictionary for us to see. Also, how do you *know* you have the correct output?

Comment: Posted the Dictionary! I'll know I have the correct output if the list I end up with are real words... Right now, most "words" in the words list look kinda like "dosifdj".

Comment: `realWords.retainAll(d); ` seems to work okay for me. The problem seems to be else where. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @luisa The code works fine, please debug your code. See the output for reference.

Comment: Your check will also run a LOT faster if you make your Dictionary a `Set<String>` rather than a `List<String>`, and presumably your dictionary doesn't have duplicate entries anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code has the following output: [abalone, abolish]
The problem must be somewhere else. Are you sure that "words" contains valid words? Try outputting it and checking manually.

```
public class Example {
    public static class Dictionary extends ArrayList<String> {

        public Dictionary() {

            this.add("abalone");
            this.add("abandon");
            this.add("abashed");
            this.add("abashes");
            this.add("abasing");
            this.add("abating");
            this.add("abdomen");
            this.add("abducts");
            this.add("abetted");
            this.add("abetter");
            this.add("abettor");
            this.add("abiding");
            this.add("ability");
            this.add("abjured");
            this.add("abjures");
            this.add("abolish");
            this.add("aborted");
            this.add("abounds");
            this.add("abraded");
            // and then more words

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> realWords = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList("abalone", "foobar", "abolish"));
        Dictionary d = new Dictionary();
        realWords.retainAll(d);
        System.out.println(realWords);
    }

}
```

EDIT: Your other attempts are functionally identical, they have the same complexity (O(words.size() * d.size()) but are longer and less obvious/clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enhance for loop

```
   List<String> realWords = new ArrayList<>();
   Dictionary d = new Dictionary();
   List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    words.add("abetted");
    words.add("ability");


    for (String word : words) {
        if (d.contains(word)) {
            realWords.add(word);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(realWords);
}
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but got the same error I got when I used "==" :(
`"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2916, Size: 2916
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at a1.Phone2Word.map(Phone2Word.java:39)" `

Line 39 corresponds to `if(words.get(i).equals(d.get(j))){`

Comment: @abdi typo in 2nd statement.  Shoud be `j < d.size()`

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, please debug your code. See the output for reference.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        words.add("abashes");
        words.add("sdqad");
        words.add("abducts");
        words.add("sadadads");

        List<String> realWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        Dictionary d = new Dictionary();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < words.size() ; i++) {
            if (d.contains(words.get(i))) {
                realWords.add(words.get(i));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(realWords);
    }
```

**output**

```
[abashes, abducts]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 streams I would suggest:

```
List<Strings> realWords = words.stream()
    .filter(d::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
```